# azure devops release number in CICD YML

Tags: azure-devops, devops, release

I use CI/CD yml file to build and deploy stages, for the deployment part I want to use below sample template:

```
- stage: DevDeploy
  displayName: Development Deployment stage
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy job
    pool:
      name: default
    environment: 'Dev'
    strategy:
      rolling:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              artifactName: 'deployment'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/deployment'
```

How can I add release number to the pipeline? [same as creation of classic release, you can see in below image:]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add release number to the pipeline?

Azure devops provides a walkthrough of **Multi-Stage** YAML pipelines for CI/CD.

The YAML file contains two parts of CI/CD, and there is currently no separate YAML for Release pipeline. So we could not define a separate release name for Multi-Stage YAML pipelines like classic release.

If you want to custom the name of the Multi-Stage YAML pipeline, you could use the `name` property in the YAML to specify the pipeline instance name:

```
name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.rr)
steps:
- script: echo hello world
```

You could check the official document [YAML getting started - Pipeline instance name](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/3d39fca3cac2bf54c16600e0a3b9e7972d4c5ef3/docs/preview/yamlgettingstarted-name.md) for some more details.